# Visual Studio prompts me to check out javascript files

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, version-control

So today Visual Studio (2013/Update1) thought it would be amusing to do a checkout every time I open a Javascript file.  It only happens with javascript files -- .css and .cs files in the same project work just fine.

I've tried diffing my project file in source control, and I don't see anything that would cause it (there are a lot of changes, because I just updated some nuget packages, but the changes all seemed to just be file includes for the swapped out .js libraries).

I've tried the obvious stuff, like rebooting and deleting my .suo file.  For now, I guess it's just a nuisance,  but I would like to fix it.

I am running Resharper 8.1, if that could have anything to do with it.

Comment: I've got the same setup and this is happening to me as well. I also have Web Essentials installed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that the latest Web Essentials update, 1.8, has fixed this issue.
This seems to be the bug we were experiencing: https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2013/issues/596